# How to start multiple microservices after docker build finished for .net projects?

Tags: docker, microservices

I have a .net solution which has 2 projects, and each project is a microservice (a server). I have a dockerfile which first installs all the dependencies which are used by both projects. Then I publish the solution:

```
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
    WORKDIR /app
    
    # Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
    COPY *.sln .
    COPY Server/*.csproj ./Server/
    COPY JobRunner/*.csproj ./JobRunner/
    RUN dotnet restore ./MySolution.sln
    
    # Copy everything else and build
    COPY . ./
    RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
    
    # Build runtime image
    FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
    WORKDIR /app
    COPY --from=build /app/out .
    ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Server.dll"]
```

When the solution is published, 2 executables are available: `Server.dll` and `JobRunner.dll`. However, I can only start only one of them in Dockerfile.

This seems to be wasteful because restoring the solution is a common step for both `Server` and `JobRunner` project. In addition this line `RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out` produces both an executable for `Server` and `JobRunner`. I could write a separate Dockerfile for each project but this seems redundant as 99% of the build steps for each project is identical.

Is there a way to somehow start 2 executables from a single file without using a script (I don't want that both services will be started in a single container)? The closest I've found is the `--target` [option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) in docker build but it probably won't work because I'd need multiple entrypoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dockerfile, change `ENTRYPOINT` to `CMD` in the very last line.

Once you do this, you can override the command by just providing an alternate command after the image name in the `docker run` command:

```
docker run ... my-image \
  dotnet JobRunner.dll
```

(In principle you can do this without changing the Dockerfile, but the `docker run` construction is awkward, and there's no particular benefit to using `ENTRYPOINT` here.  If you're using Docker Compose, you can override either `entrypoint:` or `command:` on a container-by-container basis.)